# Оптимизация кода

Tags: оптимизация

Вот я читаю форумы и все пишет "Старайтесь делать оптимизированный код". Вот скажите, что это и как делать оптимизированный код?

Comment: Покажите пример кода, может вам подскажут как его оптимизировать. Оптимизация может быть разной: уменьшение потребления памяти программой, увелечение скорости работы некоторого алгоритма или структуры данных, архитектурная оптимизация, визуальная оптимизация кода, прочее.

Comment: Нет у меня нету кода, просто при прочтении форума, возник вопрос...

Answer (score 3):

> Вот я читаю форумы и все пишет "Старайтесь делать оптимизированный код". Вот скажите, что это и как делать оптимизированный код?

Если ты задал этот вопрос, не имея кода, значит тебе пока оптимизация не нужна. Пиши для начала готовый работающий и, желательно, понятный код. Когда ты напишешь программу, ты поймёшь, достаточно ли она быстро работает. Если производительности не хватает, то только тогда надо думать об оптимизации.

Для оптимизации нужно изучить самые слабые места и оптимизировать именно их. Слабыми местами обычно являются циклы (чем больше итераций и вложенность, тем больше вероятность, что это слабое место), некоторые системные вызовы, и алгоритмы, которые имеют высокую сложность. Искать лучше эти слабые места при помощи профилировщиков.

Бывает, что люди оптимизируют код целыми днями, а получают всего 10% выигрыша в скорости, а есть те, которые очень быстро оптимизировали слабое место и получили ускорение в 10 раз. Это из-за того, что первые не усвоили этого правила и оптимизируют всё подряд.

Циклы оптимизируются обычно вынесением из него вычислений, которые можно выполнить вне цикла. Часто с этим справляется компилятор. Если слабое место - какой-то известный алгоритм (поиск, сортировка и др.), то надо выбрать вариант алгоритма с меньшей сложностью. Но он может потреблять больше памяти. Так что оптимизируя производительность, ты можешь получить код, требующий больше памяти (хотя на ПК её достаточно много). Надо найти баланс между производительностью, потреблением памяти, читабельностью кода и временем разработки.

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае оптимизация - это минимизация или максимизация какой-либо величины. В программировании под оптимизацией обычно понимают максимизацию скорости выполнения программой каких-то действий и/или минимизацию размера программы (часто одно другому противоречит).

В книгах М.Е.Фленова "C++ глазами хакера" и "Delphi глазами хакера" есть общие советы по оптимизации (не только программ). Вот краткое содержание:

1. Оптимизировать можно все. Даже там где вам кажется, что все и так работает быстро, можно сделать еще быстрее.
2. Первое, с чего нужно начинать, - это с поиска самых слабых и медленных мест.
3. Следующим шагом вы должны разобрать по косточкам все операции и выяснить где они регулярно повторяются. Начинать оптимизацию нужно именно с них.
4. (расширение предыдущего пункта) Оптимизировать одноразовые операции - это только потеря времени. Сто раз подумай, прежде чем начать мучиться с редкими операциями.
5. Нужно знать "внутренности" компьютера и принципы его работы. Чем лучше вы знаете, каким образом компьютер будет выполнять ваш код, тем лучше вы сможете его оптимизировать.
6. Для сложных расчетов можно подготовить таблицы с заранее определенными результатами и потом использовать эти таблицы в реальном режиме времени.
7. Лишних проверок не бывает. (в этом же пункте: По возможности не выполняйте проверки в цикле, а выносите все за его пределы.)
8. Не переусердствуйте с оптимизацией. Слишком большие затраты на ускорение выполнения кода могут свести на нет приложенные усилия. Ставьте перед собой реальные цели и задачи.

Comment: По поводу "внутренностей" компьютера: в книге приводится пример о том что операции с целыми числами производятся быстрее чем с числами с плавающей точкой (насколько это актуально я не проверял), а также совет не обременять процедуры/функции слишком большим количеством параметров.

Comment: С количеством параметров, может, и есть резон. Время тратиться на копирование параметров в стек. Если нужно передать, положим, большую структуру, лучше передать не ее, а указатель или ссылку. То же и с объектами.

С FPU тоже везде пишут. Но вот в CUDA операции с float занимают такое же число тактов, как и с int. В старый GPU операции с double были чуть не в 8 раз медленне, в новых, вроде бы по документации, ускорились.

Comment: п.1 -- явный бред. пп 2 и 3 -- если оптимизация важна, учитесь пользоваться средствами профилирования. Для gcc/g++ это gprof и производные. Для других инструментов -- какие-то свои.

Comment: Про первый пункт согласен, ну еще п.7 это не про оптимизацию а скорее про надежность, в остальном вроде бы вполне здравые советы, особенно последний:)

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизированный код - это код, который на выполнение какой-то задачи тратит меньше процессорного времени, чем код неоптимизированный. Как он делается - зависит от языка, от операционной системы, от машинной платформы и т.д. Везде своя специфика. Вопрос слишком общий и поэтому вряд ли Вы можете получить ответ.

Comment: Один из немногих, общих, примеров:

Плохо:

    x += 1;
    x += 1;
    x += 1;
    x += 1;
    x += 1;

Хорошо:

    x += 5;

Comment: На самом деле, можно найти какие-то общие рекомендации. Типа, сводить к минимуму количество математических операций, вызовов функций и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

> "The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet."
>   — Michael A. Jackson

Взято из википедии (хотя встречал и задолго до неё) [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)

Comment: Абсолютный бред.

Comment: Оно конечно, оптимизация -- одна из вечных тем холиваров, да и формат хэшкода не подходит для таких тем, но... Пущай такими фокусами компиляторы занимаются. Процессоры сейчас мощные, памяти много. А человек должен думать о правильности, ясности, простоте программы.
И не надо будет "думать о внутренностях компьютера" (см. выше), которые меняются достаточно быстро.

Comment: Вы просто никогда не имели дело с многочасовыми вычислениями. У меня как-то после небольших изменений одна программа вместо трех часов стала считать за полтора.

Comment: Если можно, подробнее пользователю alexlz661 на gmail.com.

Comment: Там дело было в оптимизации программы на CUDA. Дело было давно, исходники я потерял ((( Помню, там нужно было оптимизировать запросы в общую память устройства, кешировать их и минимизировать количество кернелей.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько принципов. Например, старайтесь вместо рекурсии использовать циклы(или хвостовую рекурсию)(если есть такая возможность). Или старайтесь использовать более простые математические операции, пример:

```
// вместо  
x = pow(x, 2);  
// используйте
x = x * x;  
// и т.п.
/*хотя, как меня поправили, сама pow() является inline функцией, но я думаю понятно к чему я веду*/
```

Comment: Пункт первый будет лучше читаться в виде "вместо рекурсии использовать хвостовую рекурсию" (при включённой оптимизации) (если есть такая возможность)

Comment: В Visual C++ эта функция inline, поэтому компилятор должен оптимизировать этот вызов и заменить на x*=x.

Comment: я для примера. дело в том, что когда мне эти вещи объясняли, то объясняли на паскале(в котором к стати нет pow()) и показывали на разных операциях, а функцию pow я написал потому что она первая пришла мне на ум